# How can I print a double in C++ up to a fixed precision?

Tags: c++

If I have stored a value in a `double` variable like

```
double d = pow(...)
```

and this function, let's say, evaluates to an integer, and if I print it using `cout`, it prints only the integer without trailing zeroes.

How can I print the trailing zeroes as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::fixed
#include <iomanip>      // std::setprecision

  int main () {
  double f =3.14159;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << f << '\n';
  std::cout << std::setprecision(9) << f << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.1416
3.14159
3.14159
3.141590000
```

`setprecision(int n)` sets the specified  precision

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `std::setprecision`. Something like this:

```
std::cout << std::setprecision (10) << d << std::endl;
```